# filter() piped with distinct() to select strings in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, distinct

Let's assume that I have data in a df called `data_full`. From `data_full` I get

```
data_filtered <- data_full %>% filter(ua %in% c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Where,

```
data_filtered <- data.frame(ua = c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 4), rep('c', 3)),
                        sp = c(rep('sp1', 3), rep('sp2', 3), rep('sp3', 2), rep('sp4',2)))
```

Now, I want to select the unique terms that occur in `data_filtered$sp` without breaking the pipe in the first code (`data_filtered <- data_full %>%`). Without a pipe I can simply use `unique(data_filtered$sp)`, but how can I keep it in {dplyr} language? `distinct`works in my above example, but in my dataset it doesn't since it keeps the uniqueness between `ua`. I tried to write some replication code with the ''error'' but I couldn't, so I'll print a section of the data (sorry)

[image: Here]

This is after I pipe all the way from `data_full` into `data_filtered`. In my example it would be:

```
data_filtered <- data_full %>%
     filter(ua %in% c('a', 'b', 'c')) %>% distinct(sp)
```

Is this because of "*Select only unique/distinct rows from a data frame.*" on the function description? If so, how can I get the results I want? For example, only one "**Alsophila setosa**" in my print. I want the final result to be a vector of species names.

EDIT:

As requested:

```
structure(list(`Unidade Amostral` = c("1000", "1000", "1000", 
"1000", "1000", "1000", "1000", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", 
"1001", "1001", "1001", "1001", "1003", "1003", "1003", "1003", 
"1003"), Espécie = c("Aspidosperma australe", "Cupania vernalis", 
"Matayba elaeagnoides", "Nectandra megapotamica", "Ocotea puberula", 
"Ocotea pulchella", "Parapiptadenia rigida", "Allophylus edulis", 
"Araucaria angustifolia", "Hovenia dulcis", "Machaerium paraguariense", 
"Matayba elaeagnoides", "Muellera campestris", "Nectandra megapotamica", 
"Parapiptadenia rigida", "Clethra scabra", "Ilex brevicuspis", 
"Ilex paraguariensis", "Matayba elaeagnoides", "Myrsine coriacea"
), n = c(4, 7, 14, 6, 9, 4, 5, 4, 8, 3, 4, 16, 10, 6, 4, 4, 13, 
3, 42, 12)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(`Unidade Amostral` = c("1000", 
"1001", "1003"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:15, 16:20), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: `distiinct` only returns the first unique value

Comment: So what can I use to avoid the repetition I get in my print? Is it returning each unique value base on each ua?

Comment: `unique(data_filtered$sp)` gives the same output as `%>% distinct(sp)` (except distinct returns a data.frame with single column whereas the `unique` on the vector returns the vector

Comment: I am guessing that your original data values may have leading/lagging spaces in it and thus distinct returning everything as "a" and " a" are different.  You mayuse `%>%mutate(sp = trimws(sp)) %>% distinct(sp)`

Comment: Can you try `data_full %>% filter(ua %in% c('a', 'b', 'c')) %>% mutate(sp = trimws(sp)) %>% distinct(sp)`

Comment: I tried that too. Even dowloaded as .csv to check. It's really really weird that's not returning the same result. I have no clues whatsoever. It's not really a problema because I can simply unique($), but weird.

Comment: Can you show the `dput(head(yourdata, 20))`

Comment: You may have group attribute. try `dat %>% ungroup %>% distinct(Espécie)`

Comment: Yes, that was it!

Comment: Could you explain to me what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data showed, there is a group attribute, which prevents the `distinct` from looking over the whole dataset.  We need to `ungroup` first

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   distinct(Espécie)
```

In the case of `unique` on the extracted the column as a vector, there is no group attribute, as `$` or `[[` extract will get the whole column whereas within the tidyverse environment, if there is a group attribute, the functions are applied to within each of the group elements

Comment: Thanks! I will take this into consideration in further dplyr usage

Comment: @hiperhiper i would check the `str(data)` first as this gives a lot of info before we even have to look for other issues

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for a next time